# Apply CSS class dynamically on TS file

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

I have inline HTML content on `ts` file as shown below.

```
"<div style=\"font-size: 20px;\">" + remainingAmount.toLocaleString() + "</div>"
```

Now I need to apply `color: red` according to the condition.

i.e `if(this.isSpentOver) color:red else default`

I can do this in `HTML` file like below:

```
[ngClass]="{'color-red': isSpentOver}"
```

But how can I do that on `ts` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

*.ts*

```
myMethod(){
     if (spent > totalBudget) {
          this.color = "red";
        }
  }

showChart(){
      "<div style=\"font-size: 20px;color:" + this.color + "\">" + 
                      remainingAmount.toLocaleString() + "</div>"
  }
```

**Old**

If the HTML is generated in your `component.ts` you can simply add that to the styling there, but it won't dynamically change.

```
myInnerHtml = "<div style=\"font-size: 20px;color: " + this.isSpentOver() + "\">" + remainingAmount.toLocaleString() + "</div>"

isSpentOver(): string {
  (this.spentData)? return 'red': return 'initial';
}
```

If you're looking to dynamically style generated html, one of the easier routes is to just use an ElementRef and any time your spentData changes (and the color needs to be updated) call the method that gets the elementRef and changes the color. There are a lot of solid SO questions/answers on Angular, ElementRef, and querySelector() methods so I won't drop how that works here.